# Oracle 12c double quote on password restrictions

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I've been able to use any character on my passwords successfully using double quotes like:

```
alter user example identified by "weird/@#&'pass\\";
```

I haven't had any issues with special exceptions, even /0 \ and other special cases I've seen failed before work, but, I cannot use  a double quote in my password ("), I've tried escape characters already with no success.

I see no restrictions on the Oracle Reference, so is there a way to use double quotes or is this an undocumented restriction?

Comment: I imagine the same rules apply as for [quoted identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm): "Quoted identifiers can contain any characters and punctuations marks as well as spaces. However, neither quoted nor nonquoted identifiers can contain double quotation marks or the null character (\0)". You mentioend "/0" was OK; did you mean that, or were you able to use "\0", and if so was that actually the null character?

Comment: I just tried both /0 and \0 work in the middle and the end of the password string, with no issues.

Comment: @AlexPoole: `'\0'` is not a "null character" in SQL. It's two single characters: the \ and the `0`. The backslash has no special meaning in SQL literals (at least not in standard SQL or in Oracle)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - indeed, though the docs sort of refer to that; I was mostly confused about the reference to "/0" in the question, and to escape characters, but my attempt to get clarification was itself unclear...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You said,

> but, I cannot use a double quote in my password ("), I've tried escape
>   characters already with no success.
>
> I see no restrictions on the Oracle Reference, so is there a way to
>   use double quotes or is this an undocumented restriction?

Oracle has clearly documented the exception of the `double quotation mark (")` and the `return character` in the password. Quote from the documentation about [IDENTIFIED BY clause](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8003.htm#SQLRF01503),

> Passwords can contain any single-byte, multibyte, or special
>   characters, or any combination of these, from your database character
>   set, with the exception of the double quotation mark (") and the
>   return character.

So, you cannot use double quotation mark` in the password. You would get two types of error :

```
SQL> create user test identified by "hi"hi";
create user test identified by "hi"hi"
                                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier


SQL> create user test identified by "hi""hi";
create user test identified by "hi""hi"
                               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-03001: unimplemented feature


SQL>
```